Critical points and first integral
This exercise (2.8) is from Verhulst's book. The exercise considers the following system
$$\begin{cases}
\dot{x}=x^2-y^3\\
\dot{y}=2x(x^2-y).
\end{cases}
$$
We determine the critical points
$$\begin{cases}
x^2=y^3\\
2x^3=2xy\implies x^2=y.
\end{cases} \implies (x,y)\in \left\{(0,0),(1,1),(-1,1)\right\}.
$$
Now to characterize the critical points, we usually compute the eigenvalues related to the jacobian at these points (From what I know).
The solution (Appendix 6) states immediately that the divergence of the vector field is zero, hence no attraction points, and the equation $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$ is exact (I don't understand this term). Then it mentions immediately that the first integral is
$$F(x,y)=x^2y -\frac{1}{2}x^4-\frac{1}{4}y^4.$$
I think the first integral comes from solving the equation
$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2x(x^2-y)}{x^2-y^3}$$
$$\implies (x^2-y^3)dy=2x(x^2-y)dx\implies x^2y-\frac{1}{4}y^4=\frac{1}{2}x^4-x^2y+C$$
From here I don't know how to proceed
My questions
1- What do we mean by exact equation ?
2- What theorem implies that zero divergence means no attraction points ?
3- How did the authot get the First integral ?
Thank you !


Informally, the equation $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2x(x^2−y)}{x^2−y^3}$ can be written as $$2x(x^2-y)dx-(x^2-y^3)dy=0.$$
We are then led to consider the differential form $Pdx+Qdy$ with $P=2x(x^2-y)$ and $Q=-(x^2-y^3)$.
One can check that $\partial_xQ=\partial_yP$ and in this case this is a sufficient condition for $Pdx+Qdy$ to be exact, meaning that there exists a function $F$ such that $dF=Pdx+Qdy$, i.e. $\partial_xF=P$ and $\partial_yF=Q$.
Practically, $F$ can be found by partial integration. If you then try to differentiate $F(x(t),y(t))$ with respect to $t$, where $x(t),y(t)$ is an integral curve of the system, you will find $dF/dt=P\dot{x}+Q\dot{y}=P\cdot(-Q)+Q\cdot P=0$, proving that $F$ is a first integral. See a more detailed remark below on exact equations.

I suppose that you consider a critical point $p$ to be attractive if both the eigenvalues of the jacobian $Jf(p)$ of the vector field $f$ evaluated at $p$ have strictly negative real part. Let $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ be these two eigenvalues. Then a necessary condition for $\Re(\lambda_1)$ and $\Re{(\lambda_2)}$ to be both $<0$ is $\Re{(\lambda_1)}+\Re{(\lambda_2)}<0$. Since the eigenvalues are in fact conjugate to each other, $\Re{(\lambda_1)}+\Re{(\lambda_2)}=\lambda_1+\lambda_2$ which is the trace of $Jf(p)$, i.e. the divergence of $f$ at $p$. Hence we can easily see that, if $\mathrm{div}{f}(p)\geq 0$, then $p$ cannot be attractive.

The explicit computation of $F$ (from the two equations $\partial_xF=P, \partial_yF=Q$) can be done in the following way. We integrate $\partial_xF=2x(x^2-y)$ with respect to $x$ treating $y$ as a parameter, getting
$$F(x,y)=\frac12x^4-x^2y+C(y)$$
where the integration constant $C$ depends on the parameter $y$. Now we compute $\partial_yF=\partial_y(\frac12x^4-x^2y+C(y))=-x^2+C'(y)$ and we consider the condition $\partial_yF=-(x^2-y^3)$. Equating these expressions, we get $-x^2+C'(y)=-x^2+y^3$, hence $C'(y)=y^3$ and, integrating this relation, $C(y)=\frac14y^4+c$ for an arbitrary constant $c$. We find then
$$F(x,y))=\frac12x^4-x^2y+C(y)=\frac12x^4-x^2y+\frac14y^4+c.$$


In general, a system of the form
$$\begin{cases}
\dot x = -Q \\
\dot y = P
\end{cases}
$$
is naturally associated to the differential form $Pdx+Qdy$ and the equation $\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac PQ$.
This last equation is said to be exact if $Pdx+Qdy$ is exact, i.e. if there exists $F$ such that $Pdx+Qdy=dF$. In such a case, $F$ is a first integral  of the system, and the equation $F(x,y)=0$ defines implicitely the solution $y=\phi(x)$ of $\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac PQ$. Indeed, by the implicit function theorem, $\frac{d\phi}{dx}=-\frac{\partial_xF}{\partial_yF}=-\frac PQ$.

One last question : How to deduce if there's any periodic solutions from the First integral ? Can we say that since there are no attractors, we might have centers and/or repulsors, hence the existence of periodic solutions ?
